# Trying to reference values in a php echo

Tags: php

```
print_r($record);
```

results in....

```
sObject Object ( 
    [type] => rie__Session__c 
    [id] => a0R0J00000IAhrHUAT 
    [values] => Array ( 
        [rie__Event__c] => a0I0J00000H6g5KUAR 
    ) 
    [fieldsToNull] => 
)
```

This does not work....

```
    <?php  echo   $record['rie__Event__c']?>
```

Would also like to....

```
    <?php  echo   $record['id']?>
```

Comment: Can't you see that it's an object, not an array?

Comment: `$record->id`, `$record->values['rie__Event__c']`

Comment: The `sObject` class probably has methods that return the values you want, why are you trying to access it as if it's an array?

Answer (score 1):

The first line of the `print_r()` output tells you that it's an object, not an array. To access object properties you use `->`, not `[]`.

```
<?php  echo $record->values['rie__Event__c']; ?>
<?php echo $record->id; ?>
```